# Robolectric does not bind service from another thread

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 3.4.2 and I need to test the interaction between two services.

In my test I wrote a dummy service:

```
ShadowApplication.getInstance().setComponentNameAndServiceForBindService(
        new ComponentName(SERVICE.getPackageName(), SERVICE.getClassName()),
            new Binder() {
                @Override
                public IInterface queryLocalInterface(final String descriptor) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    );
```

and it works if I invoke `BindService` directly from my test case, but if the call to `bindService` is in a different thread (like in the real application), the `onServiceConnected()` callback is never called.

```
ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot Do Something", e);
        }
        mContext.unbindService(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) { }
};

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mContext.bindService(SERVICE.createIntent()), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}).start();
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it expected to work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have good news. It works!

To solve the issue let's look at the source code. Let's look bindService method inside ShadowInstrumentation class:

```
private boolean bindService(
              final Intent intent,
              final ServiceConnection serviceConnection,
              ServiceCallbackScheduler serviceCallbackScheduler) {
            boundServiceConnections.add(serviceConnection);
            unboundServiceConnections.remove(serviceConnection);
            if (exceptionForBindService != null) {
              throw exceptionForBindService;
            }
            final Intent.FilterComparison filterComparison = new Intent.FilterComparison(intent);
            final ServiceConnectionDataWrapper serviceConnectionDataWrapper =
                serviceConnectionDataForIntent.getOrDefault(filterComparison, defaultServiceConnectionData);
            if (unbindableActions.contains(intent.getAction())
                || unbindableComponents.contains(intent.getComponent())
                || unbindableComponents.contains(
                    serviceConnectionDataWrapper.componentNameForBindService)) {
              return false;
            }
            startedServices.add(filterComparison);
            Runnable onServiceConnectedRunnable =
                () -> {
                  serviceConnectionDataForServiceConnection.put(
                      serviceConnection, serviceConnectionDataWrapper);
                  serviceConnection.onServiceConnected(
                      serviceConnectionDataWrapper.componentNameForBindService,
                      serviceConnectionDataWrapper.binderForBindService);
                };
        
            if (bindServiceCallsOnServiceConnectedInline) {
              onServiceConnectedRunnable.run();
            } else {
              serviceCallbackScheduler.schedule(onServiceConnectedRunnable);
            }
            return true;
          }
```

So to call callback it should run:

```
 onServiceConnectedRunnable.run();
```

For this, we should set a flag `bindServiceCallsOnServiceConnectedInline` in true:

```
shadowApplication.setBindServiceCallsOnServiceConnectedDirectly(true);
```

So finally code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

public class MyServiceRoboTest {
    private static final String TAG = MyServiceRoboTest.class.getCanonicalName();
    private final Context mContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
            Log.i(TAG, "MyServiceRoboTest setUp");
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    
            MyService service = Robolectric.setupService(MyService.class);
            Assert.assertNotNull(service);
    
            final ShadowApplication shadowApplication =
                    Shadows.shadowOf((Application) mContext);
    
            shadowApplication.setComponentNameAndServiceForBindServiceForIntent(
                    new Intent(mContext, MyService.class),
                    new ComponentName(mContext, MyService.class),
                    service.onBind(null));
    
            shadowApplication.setBindServiceCallsOnServiceConnectedDirectly(true);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testMyMessageManager() {
            MyManager.ServiceConnectListener serviceConnectListener = Mockito.mock(MyManager.ServiceConnectListener.class);
            MyMessageManager myMessageManager = new MyMessageManager(mContext, serviceConnectListener);

            verify(serviceConnectListener).onServiceConnected();
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me start with something philosophical :)

Despite a big effort from Google, Pivotal and community Robolectric as Android emulation is not 100% accurate or working as real Android. So expect things require or manual invocation, some workarounds or are not possible at all. That is why, I consider Robolctric as a good helper in unit testing, but should be avoided in integration tests.

Your test is not unit test definitely. You're testing that Android will follow your bind service call. All such things I tend test in integration or UI tests on emulators/real devices with Instrumentation framework.

If you want to test that your Service correctly behaves when Android invoke its callbacks. Then I would consider it is unit testing and manual invocation of the method is completely fine and proper way to do it.

Hope it hepls!

Comment: It possible if call shadowApplication.setBindServiceCallsOnServiceConnectedDirectly(true);